# Solaris mdb debugger doesn't show correct stack info

Tags: c++, debugging, assembly, solaris, coredump

I am analysing a core dump of a process under SPARC Solaris. **mdb** doesn't show functions in the stack correctly. **Why could that be?**
*No optimization compiler flags are used to build the process*.

---

**An update**

SPARC keeps return addresses in %i7 and %o7 registers. Code that doesn't manipulate these registers directly can't corrupt %i7 and %o7 unless registers are saved to memory. Memory swaps happen during thread context switches and `save, restore` instructions (under certain conditions related to register windows handling).

**Is the above a correct statement?**

---

By looking at the code and parameter values the correct call stack should look like:

```
libc_psr.so.1`memcpy+SOME_OFFSET
lib_ap.so`makeBody+0xa8
lib_ap.so`parseBody+0x1cc
lib_ap.so`parse+0x1130
lib_ap.so`queue+0xd4
0xfebbaef8(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

However, mdb replaces "makeBody, memcpy+SOME_OFFSET" pair with memcpy+0x7f0:

```
> $G
C++ symbol demangling enabled
> ::stack
libc_psr.so.1`memcpy+0x7f0(22c3b3d0, 0, 140, f8e86dc6, 6170706c, 6d756c74)
lib_ap.so`parseBody+0x1cc(f8bfbf54, 22c3b3d0, 0, 140, f8e86dc6, f8e18090)
lib_ap.so`parse+0x1130(f8bfbdb4, f8e869fe, f8e849e8, f8e849fe, fec375bc, 50cf2488)
lib_ap.so`queue+0xd4(8b9cc8, f8bfc000, 0, 0, f8d07214, 0)
0xfebbaef8(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

%o7 and %i7 registers seems to show functions correctly but %pc and %npc do not:

```
> ::regs
%g0 = 0x00000000                 %l0 = 0xff000000
%g1 = 0x00000000                 %l1 = 0x00ff0000
%g2 = 0x00000000                 %l2 = 0x0000ff00
%g3 = 0x22c3b3d0                 %l3 = 0xe06f6f6b
%g4 = 0xf8bfbf54                 %l4 = 0x00000061
%g5 = 0x00000004                 %l5 = 0x0000006d
%g6 = 0x00000000                 %l6 = 0x7efefeff
%g7 = 0xfe91ba40                 %l7 = 0x81010100
%o0 = 0x00000000                 %i0 = 0x22c3b3d0
%o1 = 0xf8e86ec6                 %i1 = 0x00000000
%o2 = 0x00000040                 %i2 = 0x00000140
%o3 = 0x74680000                 %i3 = 0xf8e86dc6
%o4 = 0xf8e86dc0                 %i4 = 0x6170706c
%o5 = 0x000000c0                 %i5 = 0x6d756c74
%o6 = 0xf8bfb048                 %i6 = 0xf8bfb0b0
%o7 = 0xf8d50058 lib_ap.so`makeBody+0xa8 %i7 = 0xf8d5025c lib_ap.so`parseBody+0x1cc

 %psr = 0xfe001006 impl=0xf ver=0xe icc=nzvc
                   ec=0 ef=4096 pil=0 s=0 ps=0 et=0 cwp=0x6
   %y = 0x00000000
  %pc = 0xfed10ce4 libc_psr.so.1`memcpy+0x7f0
 %npc = 0xfed10ce8 libc_psr.so.1`memcpy+0x7f4
  %sp = 0xf8bfb048
  %fp = 0xf8bfb0b0

 %wim = 0x00000000
 %tbr = 0x00000000
```

Comment: If you think the stack should look different, check the current instruction in `parseBody` is what  you expect. If it is, disassemble the location it calls into `makeBody` and see if it jumps to rather than calls memcpy. If none of that helps, it's possible your stack is corrupt.

Comment: parseBody pints to `sr_mrcp.so`parseBody+0x1cc: call      +0xa92fc      <0xfafbc36c>`. Am I correct that <0xfafbc36c> should be the address of makeBody? And +0xa92fc is an offset from _PROCEDURE_LINKAGE_TABLE_?

Comment: `memcpy+0x7f0` might not *actually* be memcpy; it could be some other internal libc function.  I have no experience with `mdb` or debugging into Solaris's `libc`, so IDK.

Comment: You can compare the results from `mdb` with the results from `pstack [corefilename]`.  Also, be aware that if you have core file size limits, you're likely to get a corrupted core file with incorrect stack traces.  The only useful core file size limits on Solaris a zero for no core file and unlimited for a useful core file.  Any fixed limit will likely result in useless core files.

Comment: @andrew-henle Thanks. pstack shows same results; core file size is unlimited.

Comment: Do you know what caused your process to fail and generate a core file?

Comment: Note that the stack reporting the offset of `memcpy+0x7f0` says that is in `libc_psr.so.1` - the libc functions optimized for a certain processor, but your disassembly is looking at the generic version in libc instead.

Comment: @andrew If the code fails in `memcpy` then the crash is due to a null pointer dereferencing and the null pointer is caused by heap memory corruption. However, I am not sure if `memcpy` is called.

Comment: @dmitri *the null pointer is caused by heap memory corruption.*  How do you know that the null pointer is caused by heap corruption?

Comment: @AndrewHenle `memcpy` function is called after two memory allocations. The first allocation is successful; the result of the second allocation is passed to `memcpy` and it appears to be `null`. I doubt that `malloc` failed and returned `null` as the core file size is 1.6G only.

Comment: @dmitri *I doubt that `malloc` failed and returned `null` as the core file size is 1.6G only.*  The code doesn't check for a failed `malloc()` call?  Because if the code did ask `malloc()` for 898756721 terabytes, `malloc()` **would** fail....

Comment: @AndrewHenle No, the code doesn't check. However, the code asks `malloc` for 0x140 bytes only.

Comment: @dmitri You're getting a 1.6 GB core file from what looks to be a 32-bit process.  `malloc()` may very well be returning `NULL`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I’d agree if I could explain the weird call stack (hence my question) and if 1.6G was unusual for this process. I don’t dismiss the null pointer possibility entirely.

Comment: @alanc thanks, now I realise that and disassembling makes more sense